# STOMP Spring Boot example works on one machine but not another

Tags: macos, websocket, spring-websocket, macos-monterey

I am trying to develop a Spring Boot service that uses STOMP over WebSockets.  To start out, I have been following this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/.  But this wasn't working for me on my personal machine (a MacBook Pro) and I couldn't figure out why, so I ran it on my work machine (also a MacBook Pro) and lo and behold it worked!  So I am trying to work out why the exact same code works on one machine but not on the other.

1. Both machines are running the exact same version of Chrome (116.0.5845.96) and Java (Temurin-17.0.8+7).  Both are running the code from that guide (https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket/tree/main/complete) from the command line.  The machine that works is a "15-inch, 2018" running Ventura 13.2; the one that fails is a "13-inch, 2016" running Monterey 12.6.8.
2. In both cases, I see the websocket upgrade request, and it succeeds:

```
2023-08-22T17:21:11.156+01:00 TRACE 3387 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.s.s.DefaultHandshakeHandler      : Upgrading to WebSocket, subProtocol=v12.stomp, extensions=[]
2023-08-22T17:21:11.163+01:00 TRACE 3387 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
2023-08-22T17:21:11.164+01:00 DEBUG 3387 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 101 SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS, headers={masked}
```

3. From Chrome dev tools, I then see the client send the CONNECT frame (which has a length of 60):

```
CONNECT
accept-version:1.2,1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000
```

4. On the machine that works, I see that this is received and processed correctly:

```
2023-08-22T17:18:58.600+01:00 DEBUG 9107 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.t.websocket.server.WsFrameServer     : wsFrameServer.onDataAvailable
2023-08-22T17:18:58.600+01:00 DEBUG 9107 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@23cf9265:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@2d08686c:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:58388]], Read from buffer: [0]
2023-08-22T17:18:58.600+01:00 DEBUG 9107 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@23cf9265:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@2d08686c:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:58388]], Read direct from socket: [62]
2023-08-22T17:18:58.600+01:00 DEBUG 9107 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.t.websocket.server.WsFrameServer     : Read [62] bytes into input buffer ready for processing
2023-08-22T17:18:58.600+01:00 DEBUG 9107 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.t.websocket.server.WsFrameServer     : WebSocket frame received. fin [true], rsv [4], OpCode [1], payload length [56]
2023-08-22T17:18:58.604+01:00 TRACE 9107 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.h.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator : Handling TextMessage payload=[CONNECT
ac..], byteCount=60, last=true] in StandardWebSocketSession[id=d52edcf1-f587-753d-edba-f0d86d1a433a, uri=ws://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket]
2023-08-22T17:18:58.609+01:00 TRACE 9107 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder    : Decoded CONNECT {accept-version=[1.2,1.1,1.0], heart-beat=[10000,10000]} session=null
```

The server then returns CONNECTED, and everything is fine.

5. But on the machine that does not work, I see this:

```
2023-08-22T17:21:06.066+01:00 DEBUG 3387 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.t.websocket.server.WsFrameServer     : wsFrameServer.onDataAvailable
2023-08-22T17:21:06.071+01:00 DEBUG 3387 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@4c024d8b:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@42c5ba7b:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:54475]], Read from buffer: [0]
2023-08-22T17:21:06.072+01:00 DEBUG 3387 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@4c024d8b:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@42c5ba7b:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:54475]], Read direct from socket: [634]
2023-08-22T17:21:06.073+01:00 DEBUG 3387 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.t.websocket.server.WsFrameServer     : Read [634] bytes into input buffer ready for processing
2023-08-22T17:21:06.093+01:00 DEBUG 3387 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.h.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator : StandardWebSocketSession[id=2fcea7b6-9682-2d9b-997f-de80f69825be, uri=ws://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket] closed with CloseStatus[code=1002, reason=A WebSocket frame was sent with an unrecognised opCode of [7]]
2023-08-22T17:21:06.093+01:00 DEBUG 3387 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler    : Clearing session 2fcea7b6-9682-2d9b-997f-de80f69825be
2023-08-22T17:21:06.103+01:00 DEBUG 3387 --- [nboundChannel-2] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Processing DISCONNECT session=2fcea7b6-9682-2d9b-997f-de80f69825be
```

It reads a lot more data, which isn't the expected CONNECT frame and so it closes the connection from the server side because of `A WebSocket frame was sent with an unrecognised opCode of [7]`.
I have no idea how it is reading 634 bytes - from Chrome Dev Tools I see that the client is just sending the same 60 bytes as on the working machine.  If I debug the server to see what these bytes are, I see that it contains the original HTTP Upgrade request (with what looks like garbage bytes after it - I don't even see the CONNECT frame):

```
GET /gs-guide-websocket HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Sec-WebSocket-Key: rWZnHSNWtCBaIIxRGHdFdw==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: v12.stomp, v11.stomp, v10.stomp

������[�����\�������8(~b��f���f����2v;y�����b�����
```

I have also tried using Safari, and even modifying the example to use undertow rather than tomcat as the embedded web server, but nothing helps.  I am at a loss as to what is happening, or how to debug further.

**UPDATE:**

I have used Wireshark to inspect the traffic that is being sent, and there is a difference.

The traffic from the working machine looks as you'd expect:

[Working example in Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN1NS.png)

There are three WebSocket Text messages, the first is the CONNECT from client->server, then the server replies with CONNECTED, and the client sends a SUBSCRIBE.

But this is from the non-working machine:

[Non-working example in Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Q53.jpg)

Here the client sends the CONNECT message, but then immediately seems to send a "WebSocket Continuation" - at least I think this is the client sending it, it originates from the same port (55211) but rather than being sent to the same port as the original WS connection (10011) it seems to be sent back to the original HTTP port (8080), which I don't understand.  This is the view of this continuation in Wireshark, but I'm struggling to understand what is happening here:

[Wireshark continuation details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T4sV.jpg)

This leads me to believe that the problem is at the client side.  But it is the same code with the same versions of StompJS running in the same version browser, albeit on different OS versions.

**UPDATE 2:**

This is definitely a client-side problem - if I connect to the server running on the non-working machine from a browser running on the working machine, then it works fine.  The problem seems to be specific to the browser running on the Monterey machine.

When it does not work (from the Monterey machine, using either Chrome or Safari) I see in Wireshark that the client makes *two* HTTP Upgrade requests.  This seems to be the cause of the problem - the server responds to both of them, but then the client sends the correct CONNECT frame down the first websocket but sends what looks like the HTTP request again down the second websocket.  Since this is large it is split across multiple messages but it isn't well formed and so the server disconnects.  This is what I see in Wireshark before the connection is closed:

```
WebSocket
    0... .... = Fin: False
    .100 .... = Reserved: 0x4
    .... 0111 = Opcode: Unknown (7)
    0... .... = Mask: False
    .100 0101 = Payload length: 69

Payload:

    T /gs-guide-websocket HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgra
```

```
WebSocket
    0... .... = Fin: False
    .110 .... = Reserved: 0x6
    .... 0100 = Opcode: Unknown (4)
    0... .... = Mask: False
    .110 0101 = Payload length: 101

Payload:

Host: 192.168.1.208:8080
Origin: http://192.168.1.208:8080
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: v12.stomp, v11
```

```
WebSocket
    0... .... = Fin: False
    .010 .... = Reserved: 0x2
    .... 1110 = Opcode: Unknown (14)
    0... .... = Mask: False
    .111 0011 = Payload length: 115

Payload:

tomp, v10.stomp
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: Rbeo1TFAVQ4VzllWLe1DCw==
Sec-WebSoc
```

```
WebSocket
    0... .... = Fin: False
    .110 .... = Reserved: 0x6
    .... 1011 = Opcode: Unknown (11)
    0... .... = Mask: False
    .110 0101 = Payload length: 101
    Payload

t-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh;
```

I've tried to find whether there is a known issue with WebSockets in Monterey, and all I found was a suggestion to turn off the "NSURLSession Websocket" experimental feature in Safari, but this did not help.

**UPDATE 3:**

I found this, which sounds like exactly my problem: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/726731.  And, as that post suggests, if I use a port other than 8080 ***the problem does not occur and everything works*** .

Does anyone know what is going on here?  (For the record I don't have Docker installed, so that isn't the problem)